# Probabilistic image classification using imageCategoryClassifier MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, classification

I got a classifier with my training set containing images of three types following this guide: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html

Now I want to use this classifier to classify the images of another dataset. Outputs are supposed to give me the predicted types of the images and corresponding probabilities.

I found the function "predict" to do the prediction.

Link: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/imagecategoryclassifier.predict.html

However, I have two questions

First, it says:
[labelIdx,score] = predict(categoryClassifier,imds) returns the predicted label index and score for the images specified in imds.

I don't understand this "score". It says: "The score provides a negated average binary loss per class". And the outputs of "score" are negative. So is there any way I can obtain the probability(should be [0,1]) from this "score"?

Second, my testing datasets contains images of 6 types, that is, 3 more types than my classifier. But with the function "predict", it will give a label from one of three types to each images. How can I add an extra label to point out the images that cannot be classified into any of the three types?

I think this one could be solved if I can get the probabilities from my first question. At least I could set a threshold to change the labels manually.

Any suggestions that could help solve these problems? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you can simply get probability of each sample for whole classes by calculating sth like   `exp(-score)`

Comment: @HosseinKa Thanks for your reply. Yes I think it should simply be `exp(score)`